# LESS Prevent less from adding relative url

Tags: path, less

I'm using dotLess on a MVC project and I cannot add url('') paths from imported less files.

I have the following less code:

```
@myvar : '../../';

body
{
    background-image:url('@{myvar}chosen-sprite.png');
}
```

Which generates the following css when in the main .less file, which is correct:

```
body {
    background-image: url('../../chosen-sprite.png');
}
```

The problem is that if I move this code to a second .less file on a different folder and then import that file from the main less file. E.g:

```
@import 'myFolder/mySecondfile.less
```

Now the generated CSS looks like this:

```
body {
    background-image: url('myFolder/../../chosen-sprite.png');
}
```

Is there any way to prevent that "myFolder" from being displayed there? I know I could just write the absolute path, but that would mean changing the address every time the root of the site (which happens often while testing).

Thanks

Comment: I tried replicating this using lessphp, the php port of less, and it worked the way in which you described you would like it to work. I haven't tried it the way lesscss actually does it, which the php port has wrong, but it may be worth raising it as a bug with the author.

Answer (score 9):

I'm not sure if you ever got an answer for this, but you could escape the string.

```
.body {
  background-image: ~"url('chosen-sprite.png')";
}
```

Notice the tilde and quote surrounding the entire url argument of the style. If you want to read more about it, check out [String Interpolation](http://lesscss.org/#-string-interpolation) and [Escaping Strings](http://lesscss.org/#-escaping).

Comment: I had the same issue as Jan and tried your solution with success!

Comment: Glad to hear it helped you out @jhdrn

Answer (score 0):

You should try to change the varible into `@myVar: './../../'`